# Chart.js multiple doughnut charts above pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Is it possible to create doughnut chart above pie chart with chart.js jquery. 
See, here is the example in image which i want to achieve with pie chart and doughnut chart.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

check out: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/797 they are describing your chart. It sounds like it can be done in v2.0. Possible duplicate for this stackoverflow question which also explores what you are trying: [Chart.js - Multiple Doughnut Charts on same Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866844/chart-js-multiple-doughnut-charts-on-same-canvas)